# What is this optimization problem called

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of functions $f:X \to \Bbb{R}$ (for my purposes, it is fine to assume both sets are finite).

For a probability distribution $\mu$ on $\mathcal{F}$, we define its *worst case expectation*
$$ w(\mu) := \min_{x \in X} \Bbb{E}_{f \sim \mu} [f(x)] = \min_{x \in X} \sum_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x)\mu(f).$$This quantity naturally arose from some work in combinatorics I have been doing.

Is there an established name for $w$? Have there been papers on the optimization problem of maximizing $w(\mu)$ for certain $X,\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: First, I think it should be $\mu(f)$ in the last term? Your problem appears to be a very classical stochastic optimization problem. Note that you can rewrite the problem as $\min_{x \in X} \mathbb{E}_{\xi}[L(x, \xi)]$ for some random variable $\xi$ and some function $L$. "Worst case expectation" has a different meaning for me, as this name usually refers to problems in the area of distributionally robust optimization, where more than one probability measure is involved.

Comment: you are correct, thank you. your rephrasing of the problem seems more natural. perhaps the problem is too general to have good answers, in which case I might try to rephrase my question includi additional structural properties that occur in my setting. but if someone could point to a resource on this classical problem, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x\in X$, the formula $Z_x(f):=f(x)$ defines a random variable $Z_x$ on the probability space $(\mathcal F,\Sigma,\mu)$, for some $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ over $\mathcal F$. So,
$$w(\mu)=\min_{x\in X}EZ_x.$$
There is nothing special about such a minimum, and it hardly deserves a name.